# Accessing Controllers from normal Ember.Object class

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember object like :

```
App.Obj = Ember.Object.extend({});
```

and a controller :

```
App.myController = Ember.Controller.extend({});
```

The question is can I access `myController` from `App.Obj` object? If yes how?

The scenario is:

1) I have model that created like this:

```
OlapApp.Measure = Ember.Object.extend({});
OlapApp.Measure.reopenClass({
measure:Ember.A(),
find:function(cubeUniqueName){
    var c = Ember.A();
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:9095/service.asmx/getMeasures',
        data: '{"cubeUniqueName":"'+cubeUniqueName+'"}',
        success: function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
            $.each(data,function(i,v) {
             c.pushObject(OlapApp.Measure.create(v));
            });
        }
    });
    return c;
},
findByUniqueName:function(un){

}
});
```

2) I have dropdown that when the select index of dropdown changed the setMeasure is called so I set the model for each controller:

```
OlapApp.CubeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
needs:['application','measure','dimenssion'],
content:[],
selectedValue:'',//this is the buffer for the select
realValue:'',//this is the real value
setMeasure:function(name){
    this.get('controllers.measure').set('model',OlapApp.Measure.find(name));
       this.get('controllers.dimenssion').set('model',OlapApp.Dimenssions.find(name));
},
actions:{
    refreshCubes:function(){
        this.set('model','');
        this.set('model',OlapApp.Cubes.findAll());

    }
}
});
```

3) Now with this model I create a list of item. I want when user click at any of this item I send uniqueName of item to OlapApp.Measure.findByUniqueName() and in this method get the model and search in model to find correct record. At this time I have 2 problem I cant get model and I don't know how to search in model.
I try to use you way and I have some problem

- I have ArrayController and I get and error when use Ember.ArrayController.create()

If you ask your self why I'm using this way and not ember way you can find some information in this my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811343/maping-nested-json-to-ember-data-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet it's not really clear what you are trying to achieve and there is surely a better (more ember like) way, but to access your controller is straight forward, first use `create` instead of `extend` because since this controller is not thight to nowhere ember will not instantiate it for you so you have to do it yourself:

```
App.myController = Ember.Controller.create({
  someProperty: 'hello'
});
```

And then use the full name to access the instance you previously created:

```
App.Obj = Ember.Object.extend({
  myFunction: function() {
    console.log(App.myController.get('someProperty')); // should print 'hello'
  }
});
```

The order is important here, so first create your controller before you try to access it.

To test that it's working instantiate your `App.Obj` and then call the function like:

```
App.obj = App.Obj.create();
obj.myFunction(); // should print 'hello'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: im updating my question

Comment: when i'm using `create` instead of `extend` i get an error that say `Object [object Object] has no method 'create'

Comment: @MBehtemam, which object do you mean?